# Generate JSON object with transactionReceipt

Tags: objective-c, json, iphone-sdk-3.0, app-store-connect, storekit

I've been the past days trying to test my first in-app purchse iphone application. Unfortunately I can't find the way to talk to iTunes server to verify the transactionReceipt.

Because it's my first try with this technology I chose to verify the receipt directly from the iPhone instead using server support. But after trying to send the POST request with a JSON onbject created using the JSON api from google code, itunes always returns a strange response (instead the "status = 0" string I wait for).

Here's the code that I use to verify the receipt:

```
- (void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    NSString *receiptStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:transaction.transactionReceipt encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"algo mas",@"receipt-data",nil];

    NSString *jsonString = [jsonDictionary JSONRepresentation];
    NSLog(@"string to send: %@",jsonString);

    NSLog(@"JSON Created");
    urlData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];

    //NSURL *sandboxStoreURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt"]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSLog(@"will create connection");
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

maybe I'm forgetting something in the request's headers but I think that the problem is in the method I use to create the JSON object.

HEre's how the JSON object looks like before I add it to the HTTPBody :

```
    string to send: {"receipt-data":"{\n\t\"signature\" = \"AUYMbhY

       ...........

D0gIjEuMCI7Cn0=\";\n\t\"pod\" = \"100\";\n\t\"signing-status\" = \"0\";\n}"}
```

The responses I've got:

> complete response {
>       exception = "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property list parsing failed while attempting to read unquoted string. No allowable characters were found. At line number: 1, column: 0.";
>       status = 21002;
>   }

Thanks a lot for your guidance.

Comment: Nowhere in the documentation does it say that the `transactionReceipt` can be interpreted as a UTF-8-encoded string

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have just fixed that after 2 days of struggling. You have to encode receipt using Base64 before inserting into json object. Like that (Ruby):

```
dataForVerification = {"receipt-data" => Base64.encode64(receipt)}.to_json
```

Base64 is not mentioned anywhere in the official docs (at least for SDK 3.0), only on a couple of blogs.

For instance, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298998/verify-receipt-for-in-app-purchase) the guy encodes the receipt in Base64 before passing it to the PHP server, but does not decode it back in PHP, thus sending Base64-encoded string to iTunes.

Comment: Thank's a lot for your answer!!

Comment: The current In App Purchase Programming Guide mentions base 64 encoding in step 1. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH104-SW1

Answer (score 2):

Re: "21002: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: propertyListFromString parsed an object, but there's still more text in the string.:"

I fixed a similar issue in my code by wrapping the receipt data in {} before encoding.

The resulting receipt looks like:

```
{
    "signature" = "A[...]OSzQ==";
    "purchase-info" = "ew[...]fQ==";
    "pod" = "100";
    "signing-status" = "0";
}
```

Here's the code I use:

```
receipt = "{%s}" % receipt    // This step was not specified - trial and error
encoded = base64.b64encode(receipt)
fullpost = '{ "receipt-data" : "%s" }' % encoded
req = urllib2.Request(url, fullpost)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Apple's Response:

```
{"receipt":{"item_id":"371235", "original_transaction_id":"1012307", "bvrs":"1.0", "product_id":"com.foo.cup", "purchase_date":"2010-05-25 21:05:36 Etc/GMT", "quantity":"1", "bid":"com.foo.messenger", "original_purchase_date":"2010-05-25 21:05:36 Etc/GMT", "transaction_id":"11237"}, "status":0}
```

Good luck!