# Is it possible to implement per-iTunes account DRM for in-app purchased content?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, drm

The [receipt](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH104-SW1) Apple returns from a purchase does not include the iTunes account information of the user that purchased the content and there also doesn't seem to be way of having Apple verify if a given device UUID belongs to an iTunes account.

Is there anyway to implement a secure DRM system that allows users to purchase content once and be able to use the content for all on all the devices associated with their iTunes account?

If there's a way to replay a receipt or spoof information, I don't consider it a secure DRM system.

*[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581246/how-can-my-server-securely-authenticate-iphone-in-app-purchase), and subsequently, [my answer and its comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581246/how-can-my-server-securely-authenticate-iphone-in-app-purchase/1794470#1794470), sparked my curiosity about this.*

Comment: Both of your links point to your answer to the other question.

Comment: Fixed the first link. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Answer (score 1):

I think apple doesn't want you to modify their DRM system or make a new one...  You could [Tell Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/itunesapp.html) about the problem and they *may* be able to help you.

The receipt wouldn't include any account/private information since the receipt information can be read by most apps, it wouldn't want that information going around to anyone.

All I could think is to ask the user to reenter their id and/or password.