# how does Auto-renewable in app purchase / subscription renew itself in iphone

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am trying to understand how the auto-renewal part works. So far i went through

[Verify receipt for in App purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298998/verify-receipt-for-in-app-purchase)

http://www.phpriot.com/articles/verifying-app-store-receipts-php-curl

and Apple Documentation. I have got the App purchasing part complete but am not able to get the auto-renewal flow of it.

when the purchase expires the apple server response has status:21002 the receipt is valid but has expired.

what i am trying to understand is 
WHO triggers the new purchase? app store itself in the backend?
How does the app get to know that renewal has happened? or in other words, how does the renewal certificate reach application for processing?

Br,
Darshan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The App Store does the charging when the auto renewable subscription is expired. Your application is not informed when this happens.  When you validate an auto renewable receipt  that has been extended your server receives an additional receipt with the new expire date.

Documented here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/RenewableSubscriptions/RenewableSubscriptions.html

Comment: alright. Now does the auto renewals work on test / sandbox . because I am not able to get it to work with sandbox servers.

Comment: As a note, you should be checking/validating the receipt regardless.