# (iphone) base64 encoding

Tags: iphone, base64, encode

I get KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE somewhere (stack trace shows it's happening in main loop but won't give me more details because it seems that memory got corrupted in previous loop. I have all the settings to see debug output correctly)

When I remove calling the following code, the symptom goes away.
([Verify receipt for in App purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298998/verify-receipt-for-in-app-purchas)e)

```
- (NSString *)encode:(const uint8_t *)input length:(NSInteger)length {
    static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
    uint8_t *output = (uint8_t *)data.mutableBytes;

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < length; i += 3) {
        NSInteger value = 0;
        for (NSInteger j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
                value <<= 8;

                if (j < length) {
                        value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
                }
        }

        NSInteger index = (i / 3) * 4;
        output[index + 0] =                    table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
        output[index + 1] =                    table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
        output[index + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
        output[index + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    }

    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
}
```

I see there are other ways of getting base64 encoding,    [How do I do base64 encoding on iphone-sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392464/any-base64-library-on-iphone-sdk)
What I find weird is that the 'length' is computed differently.
((length +2 /3) * 4 above, and lentext*4/3+4 below.
Can anyone tell what is going on?
Beside, using the below code, I get 'receipt data-malformed' error when I pass the encoded data to apple server.

```
+ (NSString *) base64StringFromData: (NSData *)data length: (int)length {
int lentext = [data length]; 
if (lentext < 1) return @"";

char *outbuf = malloc(lentext*4/3+4); // add 4 to be sure

if ( !outbuf ) return nil;

const unsigned char *raw = [data bytes];

int inp = 0;
int outp = 0;
int do_now = lentext - (lentext%3);

for ( outp = 0, inp = 0; inp < do_now; inp += 3 )
{
    outbuf[outp++] = base64EncodingTable[(raw[inp] & 0xFC) >> 2];
    outbuf[outp++] = base64EncodingTable[((raw[inp] & 0x03) << 4) | ((raw[inp+1] & 0xF0) >> 4)];
    outbuf[outp++] = base64EncodingTable[((raw[inp+1] & 0x0F) << 2) | ((raw[inp+2] & 0xC0) >> 6)];
    outbuf[outp++] = base64EncodingTable[raw[inp+2] & 0x3F];
}

if ( do_now < lentext )
{
    char tmpbuf[2] = {0,0};
    int left = lentext%3;
    for ( int i=0; i < left; i++ )
    {
        tmpbuf[i] = raw[do_now+i];
    }
    raw = tmpbuf;
    outbuf[outp++] = base64EncodingTable[(raw[inp] & 0xFC) >> 2];
    outbuf[outp++] = base64EncodingTable[((raw[inp] & 0x03) << 4) | ((raw[inp+1] & 0xF0) >> 4)];
    if ( left == 2 ) outbuf[outp++] = base64EncodingTable[((raw[inp+1] & 0x0F) << 2) | ((raw[inp+2] & 0xC0) >> 6)];
}

NSString *ret = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:outbuf length:outp encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
free(outbuf);

return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m using this very small library for encode/decode Base64: http://imthi.com/blog/programming/iphone-sdk-base64-encode-decode.php

It does its work and I assume you use a similar version of it. Did you try to call `+initialize` before the first usage?