# Short IAP Receipt

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

We have an app in production right now that sends IAP receipts to our server that are obviously too short and not verified by apple by our server. The long receipts that get properly verified by Apple are 3192 in length. The short receipts are all 28 in length.

Does anyone have any idea why this might happen?

--

The short receipts are like: "Y29tLnVydXMuaWFwLjM4Nzg..."

The long receipts are like: "ewoJInNpZ25hdHVyZSIgPSAiQXNBcUNJZ05hVmhEeDNtV1AwU0dDWGd0WUlPRmh4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\r\nOUlDSXhNRGdpT3dvSkltRndjQzFwZEdWdExXbGtJaUE5SUNJMU..."

Comment: a coding error? what's in your logs?

Comment: This only happens in production so unfortunately there are no logs. It also seems like about 40% of the time, the receipts are coming back as the long valid type.

Comment: its production, so you have no logs? How does that logic work?

Answer (score 3):

This is receipt from "fake" payment made with iAP Cracker by urus (available on jailbroken devices).
You can view receipt content through base64 decoding.

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing as a short receipt in in-App Purchase. You might be doing something. eg Using wrong HTTP methods for sending the receipts to server i.e. using GET Method(instead of POST method)

Further Explanation in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298998/verify-receipt-for-in-app-purchase) thread.